# I am an Indian holding an Estonian Temporary Residence Permit. Do I need a UK transit visa?

Tags: uk, transit-visas, permits, estonia

I am an Indian and have a Temporary Residence Permit from Estonia. I shall be transiting in UK towards Spain. Do I need transit visa?  In the exemptions it says if you have a common format residence permit issued by an European Economic Area then you do not need a transit visa. Thanks

Comment: I suspect that what you really need to know is whether the Estonian Temporary Residence Permit you have is a "common formate residence permit." If that's your real question, please ask it as a new and separate question using the "Ask Question" button that appears at the upper right of these pages. It'd help generate good answers if you attach an image of your Permit to the question, after obscuring your personal details so the details are not visible.

Comment: Also more information on what the permit looks like would be helpful. If it is a plastic card with **residence permit** printed at the bottom, then it is very likely a **common format residence permit**.  Adding an image, with your personal information bloted out, of the front side (with your photo) of the card to your question would give you a swift answer.